# Prove $A \equiv B \vdash (\forall x)A \equiv (\forall x)B$ without relying on equivalence theorem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, predicate-logic

The given rules of inference for me to use are here: [rules of inference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVIM9.png)

In addition, I was taught the deduction theorem, the ping-pong tautology, specialization and dual specialization (derived rules).

My solution:

Using Deduction Theorem, it suffices if we prove $$A \equiv B, (\forall x)A \vdash (\forall x)B.$$ 
Hilbert proof:

1) $A ≡ B\quad\langle\text{hypothesis}\rangle$

2) $(\forall x)A\quad\langle\text{hypothesis}\rangle$

3) $A\quad\langle\text{2 + Specialization}\rangle$

I couldn't move past step 3 because I did not know where to go. Any help on this question is appreciated.

***Note:*** This is practice problem is for first year discrete mathematics for engineers course.

Comment: What does that imply? What should be the next step?

Comment: The unusal A[x] seems nonsensical.  Here is a useful list or rules https://i.stack.imgur.com/I69BU.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did this, not sure if it's correct or not.
[image]